# Rubyish way of adding many variables to a class

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I've been working on a game (more of a web toy if anything) that requires a long list of countries to simulate, and I've managed to get it to work, but I can't help but feel that my solution is neither a Rubyish nor elegant way of doing it.

The code looks a bit like this:

```
class Countries
    include Singleton

    def get(tag)
        return eval "@#{tag}"
    end

    def initialize
        @array = []

        @afghanistan = Country.new("Afghanistan", [:authoritarian, :reactionary, :sunni, :capitalist, :militarist, :southern_asia, :unstable])
        @afghanistan.gdp = 20444
        @afghanistan.population = 26023
        @array << :afghanistan

        @albania = Country.new("Albania", [:hybrid, :conservative, :sunni, :capitalist, :pacifist, :southern_europe])
        @albania.gdp = 13276
        @albania.population = 2893
        @array << :albania
    #and so on and so forth
    end
    attr_accessor :array
end

countries = Countries.instance
puts countries.get("usa").name
puts
for i in 0..(countries.array.size-1)
    puts countries.get(countries.array[i]).name
end
```

And I get the expected output of

```
United States

Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
...
```

But ideally an elegant solution would not require .get(), and this really doesn't seem like a Ruby-like way of solving this issue. Is there a better-practice way of doing this?

I mostly learned the little bit I know from Stack Overflow, the Ruby docs, and testing, so it's very possible I have violated a lot of best practices along the way. The Country class's initializer takes a string for the name and an array of tags to add, while other properties are intended to be added in separate lines.

Comment: The first thing you **absolutely** want to do is store the countries inside a hash

Comment: @DamianoStoffie Do you mean replacing the array or replacing the class?

Comment: The solution by @spickermann is one that I would recommend, but there are some bigger issues here regarding class design. It might be worth reading up on the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), especially the Single Responsibility Principle and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store the countries` details in a file (e.q. countries.yml or a csv file) or a database:

```
# in countries.yml
afganistan:
  name: Afganistan
  tags:
    - authoritarian
    - reactionary
    - sunni
    - capitalist
    - militarist
    - southern_asia
    - unstable
  gdp: 20444
  population: 26023
albania:
  name: Albania
  tags:
    ...
    ...
```

Then your class simplified to:

```
require 'yaml'

class Countries
  include Singleton

  def get(country)
    @countries[country]
  end

  def initialize
    @countries = {}

    YAML.load_file('countries.yml').each do |country_key, options|
      country = Country.new(options['name'], options['tags'])
      country.gdp = options['gdp']
      country.population = options['population']

      @countries[country_key] = country
    end

    @countries.keys # just to keep the interface compatible with your example 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I considered using a JSON file, but it seemed like more hassle than it was worth.

Answer (score 2):

There are hundreds of ways you can DRY your code, but your error is essentially not using a [hash data stucture](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) (or an external file, as suggested).

This is how I would do it, I made some assumptions, hope this helps!

```
# I'll assume that Country is an actual class with a purpose, and not a simple
# structure.
Country = Struct.new(:name, :tags, :gdp, :population)

# list of all the countries
COUNTRIES_TABLE = [
  ["Afghanistan", [:authoritarian, :reactionary], 20444, 26023],
  ["Albania", [:hybrid, :conservative], 13276, 2893]
  # etc..
]

COUNTRIES = COUNTRIES_TABLE.map { |e| Country.new(*e) }
# we could have directly defined the hash instead of a table, but this keeps
# everything more DRY
COUNTRIES_HASH = COUNTRIES.map {|e| [e.name, e]}.to_h

puts COUNTRIES_HASH["Albania"].name

COUNTRIES_HASH.map do |k,v|
  puts v.name
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, although I think having 3 separate objects to get from the table to the hash seems like a bit much. You know better, though.